# Python, how to remove an item from one list and add it to another?

Tags: python-3.x

Just wanna say i'm a beginner so please be patient with me.

Questions:

**1**. How do i remove items from a `list(firstlist)`, and then add it onto another `list(secondlist)`?

```
firstlist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

secondlist = []
```

**2**. How to use `pop()` and `remove()`, and how to use it in this situation?

So I was wondering, the book tells me I would use the index of the item with the `pop()` method.

```
firstlist.pop(1)
```

And I could use the `remove()` method if i know the value of the item.

```
firstlist.remove('b')
```

Wouldn't it be easier to just use the `remove()` method? Hope this makes sense.

Edit: Let's say if the list has names instead. How do i approach this?

Comment: `.remove()` is less efficient because it has to find the value first, where as pop just removes the index immediately.

Comment: It wouldn't be easier to use `remove` if you didn't know the value of the item. It also would be a problem if you have multiple objects that compare the same.

Answer (score 6):

To remove from one list and add to another using both methods you can do either of the following:

**pop**:

```
secondlist.append(firstlist.pop(1))
```

**remove**:

```
item = 'b'

firstlist.remove(item)
secondlist.append(item)
```

As for why one method over the other, it depends a lot on the size of your list and which item you want to remove. Assuming your list is `firstlist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

If you want to remove the first item, then `remove` will be faster than `pop`

```
firstlist.pop(0)
183 ns ± 4.64 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

firstlist.remove('a')
130 ns ± 2.45 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

But if you want to remove the last item, then `pop` is faster

```
firstlist.pop(3)
161 ns ± 2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

firstlist.remove('d')
182 ns ± 5.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

This is because, as mentioned in the comments, `remove` will search your entire list for the first occurrence of the item. This difference will be magnified for longer lists:

```
firstlist = [x for x in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']

firstlist.pop(25)
938 ns ± 19.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

firstlist.remove('z')
1.28 µs ± 21.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use pop, python remove index and return value of item, in remove method it is not happen:

```
first_list=[1,2,3]
second_list=[]
second_list.append(first_list.pop(2))
print(second_list)
```

output

```
[3]

print(first_list)
```

output

```
[1,2]
```

But remove is most easy than pop certainly, work with values is the best way, but sometimes we need work with index, I like pop because returns the value of item.

I hope to be helped in something

Comment: This makes sense, but i'm wondering if there were names instead of numbers.  first_list = ['james', 'john', 'tony', 'will']. Is there an easier method to remove the value by not having to remove it with its index.

Comment: You can get a index using first_list.index('text_value')

Comment: Then you can use index method first_list.index(&#39;text_value&#39;) and to work with the  result